# Detect when the Chrome for iOS address bar is showing

Tags: javascript, ios, css, google-chrome, web-applications

I have set the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` to true in my web app's head section. All good, Chrome tries to hide the address bar when possible to give more room to the web app.

Problem is that my app's navigation is on the top and goes behind the address bar during that time. I was wondering if there is a way I could detect when the address bar is showing and dropping the navigation below the address bar.

If I remove the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` meta tag, address bar shows, but the navigation still goes behind it. For some reason Chrome sets the window size to the size of the screen, but pulls the address bar on top of it.

Is anyone aware of any solutions to this?

Comment: This is driving me crazy, too. Exactly the same issue. When the user's scroll delta is negative, then the address bar pops in, hiding my navigation. The resize event is even fired.

Comment: Yeah, haven't been able to find a proper solution to this so far.

Comment: Mehdi:  is the issue resolved. Me too facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is a workaround around this actually; you just have to force your app to scroll down by 1px (enough to hide the Chrome address bar) :

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Already scrolled?
  if(window.pageYOffset !== 0) return;

  window.scrollTo(0, window.pageYOffset + 1);
}, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working. The address bar hides as always, but it takes a few seconds to do so. If I remove the `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` tag, the address bar stays there, but still covers my navigation on the top. This is what I found, might be a bug as it doesn't happen in the previous versions of chrome. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/nR1c6xyn13g/7gy-RKvxa04J